# Initializing SCORM using APIWrapper.js always returns false

Tags: javascript, wrapper, moodle, scorm

I am new to SCORM and I found a library at http://pipwerks.com/downloads/

I tried using the sample code in SCORM Cloud, and it worked.

```js
//Using pipwerks namespace, SCORM 1.2

var success = pipwerks.SCORM.init();

if(success){
  var status = pipwerks.SCORM.get("cmi.core.lesson_status");
  if(status != "completed"){
    success = pipwerks.SCORM.get("cmi.core.lesson_status", "completed");
    if(success){
       pipwerks.SCORM.quit();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is `pipwerks.SCORM.init()` always returns false.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the wrapper can't find the API object that is provided by the LMS.

Make sure you are running this code within the context of an LMS, and that the LMS is providing the API object as required.

That wrapper also logs a trace, but only if pipwerks.debug.isActive is true.  Set that to true, run it in Firefox, and open the Console in Firebug.

It may be that the API object is fine, and that something else is going wrong.  Check that trace, it'll help.